# How to add objects to prototype cells in interface builder

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, interface-builder

Previously i've been able to design the basic look of the UITableView protoype cell in interface builder by dragging objects onto it etc.

I'm trying to do this now with the iPad master detail template but interface builder won't allow it.

I know it can be done programmatically or by creating a seperate .xib but it makes sense to do it this way as it's much more intuitive being able to see how it will look in the actual table view.

[image: Previously]

[image: Now]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Click on the prototype cell.
- Open the Attributes Inspector (<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd>)
- Under the Table View Cell section, change the style to Custom.

Now you can drag whatever object you like onto the cell.

Comment: Damn that little sucker was hidden behind a collapsed Table View Cell section in the attributes inspector.